# Typescript not recognized in VSCode

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, next.js, compilation, tailwind-css

I'm working on a new NextJS project w/ Typescript and Tailwind CSS.  I'm working on Mac Ventura 13.3.1.

I am importing dummy used data via the jsonplaceholder API.

In my users/page.tsx component, I am importing users and displaying their name and email.

```
import React from 'react'

interface User {
  id: number
  name: string
}

const UsersPage = async () => {
  const res = await fetch(
    'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users',
    {
      cache: 'no-store'
    }
  )
  const users: User[] = await res.json()

  return (
    <>
      <h1>Users</h1>
      <p>{new Date().toLocaleTimeString()}</p>
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {users.map(user => <tr key={user.id}>
            <th>{user.email}</th>
          </tr>)}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </>
  )
}

export default UsersPage
```

Notice that the User interface does not have `email` set to a string type.  However, my code still compiles and user emails are being displayed on the screen.  My understanding of Typescript is that this shouldn't be happening without explicitly declaring the shape of the User object.

I'm also noticing that when I hover over `User[]`, I do not get an intellisense popup displaying the type signature.  All of this is leading me to think that VSCode is not set up to recognize Typescript.

I have the following relevant extensions installed:

Babel ES6/ES7
DaisyUISnippet
ES7+ React/Redux/React-Native snippets
GitHub Copilot
Javascript Snippet Pack
Javascript and Typescript Nightly
Tailwind CSS Intellisense
Simple React Snippets

My tsconfig.json looks like this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "bundler",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "incremental": true,
    "plugins": [
      {
        "name": "next"
      }
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["next-env.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx", ".next/types/**/*.ts"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

And my package.json looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "next-app-2",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/node": "20.10.1",
    "@types/react": "18.2.39",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.2.17",
    "autoprefixer": "10.4.16",
    "eslint": "8.54.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "14.0.3",
    "next": "14.0.3",
    "postcss": "8.4.31",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "tailwindcss": "3.3.5",
    "typescript": "5.3.2"
  }
}
```